# if external disk found by terminal applescript

Tags: terminal, applescript, disk-utility, external-disk

Hey so MacBooks have this nasty habit of not mounting external disks when plugged in before... [reference link](https://appletoolbox.com/2017/03/mac-macbook-doesnt-recognize-external-drives-troubleshooting-tips/#Terminal_to_the_Rescue)

the solution is quite simple with terminal eject the disk and the manually unplug replug the drive.

I'd like to make a small AppleScript that can do the whole process of looking for the disk and if found eject it. This is what i got, but I'm stuck on recognising if the external disk is found by terminal...

```
tell application "Terminal"
do script "echo \"diskutil list\"" in window 1
if exists disk2 then
    do script "echo \"diskutil info disk2\"" in window 1
    do script "echo \"diskutil eject disk2\"" in window 1
    do script "echo \"diskutil list\"" in window 1
end if
end tell
```

the error i get is The variable disk2 is not defined.
questions are:
1) if i print the diskutil list, how would i define variables for all the external disk terminal found?
2) see if it's mounted, if not try to mount, if fails eject?

Comment: I'd just try mounting everything you find. Have a look at "Try...End Try" blocks. They have the advantage of failing silently. This can save you a LOT of "if exists..." and other repetitive coding. Be aware that it's best to put your try-end try statements in *after* you get the basic algorithm working I put them in, then --comment them out after I test each part of the script. It's nice Not to get an Apple Script dialog, when your just trying to read a book.

Comment: I would, on principle, disregard the advice given by @WayfaringStranger here.  In general, that is **not** how to use nor why one would implement error catching, and a lot of "repetitive `if exists...`" coding can be laborious, no doubt, but is _absolutely_ the correct way to do things.  But, since @Rottjung is a C++ programmer, I suspect they already know this, so this comment is aimed at other readers in general who don't want to pick up bad habits in scripting.

Comment: @CJK Wait until you get five pages into your "if exists". Like the ancient "go to" controversy, Try-End try blocks can get rid of massive piles of ugly code, and give you a much more human readable, and maintainable, product.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger As with anything in life, when one understands how and why a rule exists, then one knows precisely how and when to break the rule effectively.  But I would personally not be in a rush to encourage scripting newbies to do this, given that they typically rely on this poor technique a lot, causing a ton of problems in their scripts that are solved by eliminating every single `try` block.  I'd also guess that if you have five pages' worth checking for existence of things, there's probably a better way to approach your task.

Comment: Yes, you are correct about the newbs taking the well trodden path. I've been scripting since AppleScript came out, and there are times when condensing piles of code into a few statements is the way to go. My eyes get tired looking at too many nested "If thens". The "try...end try" block  is also a sometimes useful tool when debugging. When things start going funny, the "try end try" blocks are easily commented out, which can make it easy to find where a fatal error is coming from. It's best to make darn sure you've got the code down good before enclosing it in try end try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually writing a shell script, and the AppleScript context seems rather superfluous at the moment.  If you're predominantly using shell commands, you may want to consider writing a shell script instead.

I've employed a little of both because they each have their usefulness in this situation: the shell commands are necessary to retrieve the disk information via `diskutil`, since AppleScript has no inbuilt means of getting that information by itself; but then rather than mess around with `grep`, `awk`, or `sed` to pattern match text from the raw output, we can invoke the `-plist` option to return the output as XML-formatted property list data, which AppleScript can be very good at handling.

**1. Retrieving a list of local disks and volumes**

Locally attached disks and volumes have a blockdevice inode in the folder `/dev`, so getting a list of disks is pretty easy with AppleScript:

```
use application "System Events"

property devices : a reference to files in folder "/dev"
property disknodes : a reference to (devices whose name begins with "disk")

set diskinfo to name of disknodes
```

With my USB drive attached, I get this list of inodes:

```
    --> {"disk0", "disk0s1", "disk0s2", "disk1", "disk1s1", 
         "disk1s2", "disk1s3", "disk1s4", "disk2", "disk2s1"}
```

**2. Isolating the desired volumes**

To filter the list so that we only run the appropriate utilities on the appropriate disks or volumes, `diskutil` now does its part.  We can create a shell process from inside AppleScript rather than doing it via *Terminal*.  The relevant shell command is this:

```
diskutil info -plist <disk|volume>
```

To execute this from AppleScript, use the `do shell script` command:

```
do shell script "diskutil info -plist" & id
```

where `id` is the name of a disk retrieved from earlier and stored in `diskinfo`.  You can't pass in the entire list all at once, so we have to iterate through the list and run the command once for each item:

```
use scripting additions

delete every property list item
repeat with id in diskinfo
    set shellcmd to "diskutil info -plist " & id
    set plist to do shell script shellcmd
```

With the property list data returned by `diskutil`, AppleScript can turn it into a `property list` object.  The property list data returned by invoking `diskutil info` is all contained within a single level, so there's no hierarchy to traverse.  The great thing with `property list` objects is that AppleScript can transform them into a `record`, which then becomes really easy to retrieve values:

```
    make property list item with properties {name:id, text:plist}
    tell the value of property list item id as record to if ¬
        (its |Ejectable|) and (not its WholeDisk) and ¬
        (its MountPoint = "") then set the contents of id ¬
        to its {disk:ParentWholeDisk, volume:DeviceIdentifier}
end repeat
```

In a single line, AppleScript has read the property list data, and discarded any disk that is:

1. Not ejectable;
2. Is a "whole" disk (i.e. not a mountable volume);
3. Has an identifiable mount point on the system.

It also bins all the useless data we don't need, and returns only the name of the partition and its parent disk.  These will only be *ejectable* disks (so not the recovery and boot disks, and not your computer's hard disk), and will be mountable volumes that are not currently mounted.  For me, and my single USB drive, which I unmounted first, I got this record list back:

```
set unmounted to records of diskinfo
    --> {{disk:"disk2", volume:"disk2s1"}}
```

**3. Mounting and ejecting each volume**

The parsing of the data is now done, so now you can run `diskutil` operations on the appropriate disks.  You have the choice of either mounting individual volumes, or mounting an entire disk (which will mount all of its volumes).  The method is the same for each: iterate through our record list stored in the variable `unmounted` and use either the `disk` or the `volume` from each item as an argument for the appropriate shell command:

```
diskutil mount <volume>
diskutil mountDisk <disk>
diskutil eject <disk>
```

The AppleScript loop looks like this:

```
repeat with diskitem in unmounted
    set shellcmd to "diskutil mount " & diskitem's volume
    try
        do shell script shellcmd
    on error
        set shellcmd to "diskutil eject " & diskitem's disk
        try
            do shell script shellcmd
        end try
    end try
end repeat
```

`do shell script` returns on success the output to `stdout`.  After successfully mounting my disk, the messages pane in *Script Editor* contained:

```
"Volume USB on disk2s1 mounted"
```

I haven't instigated a situation that forces my drive not to mount, but typically, upon failure of any shell command (that is, whenever a shell command returns a non-zero status), `do shell script` throws an error.  This will be caught by the `try` block, which will redirect the script to execute another shell command responsible for ejecting the drive.  This is also in its own `try` block in case it, too, returns a non-zero status, in which case the script will continue onto the next volume.

Below is the final script with some additional modifications.  The script will return the original unmounted record list with extra information appended to each disk item reporting the outcome of the attempt to mount and/or eject the volume.  A complete failure will simply be reported with `false`.  So my final script result looked like this:

```
--> {{disk:"disk2", volume:"disk2s1", result:"Volume USB on disk2s1 mounted"}}
```

---

#### The final script

```
use application "System Events"

property devices : a reference to files in folder "/dev"
property disknodes : a reference to (devices whose name begins with "disk")

set diskinfo to name of disknodes

use scripting additions

delete every property list item
repeat with id in diskinfo
    set shellcmd to "diskutil info -plist " & id
    set plist to do shell script shellcmd
    make property list item with properties {name:id, text:plist}
    tell the value of property list item id as record ¬
        to if (its |Ejectable|) ¬
        and (not its WholeDisk) ¬
        and (its MountPoint = "") then set ¬
        id's contents to {disk:its ParentWholeDisk ¬
        , volume:its DeviceIdentifier ¬
        , result:missing value}
end repeat

set unmounted to records of diskinfo

repeat with diskitem in unmounted
    set shellcmd to "diskutil mount " & diskitem's volume
    try
        do shell script shellcmd
        set diskitem's result to the result
    on error
        set shellcmd to "diskutil eject " & diskitem's disk
        try
            do shell script shellcmd
            set diskitem's result to the result
        on error E
            set disk item's result to E
        end try
    end try
end repeat

return unmounted
```

Comment: I have a question regarding `delete every property list item`... Which property list are the items being deleted from, and why is it necessary?

Comment: It's deleted from _System Events_, which owns the `property list item` objects at the top level.  When creating an orphaned `property list item` that hasn't been read from a `property list file`, _System Events_ stores them in a temporary container, although I don't know where (likely a temporary file in a temporary directory).  They usually expire after about 5 minutes of continuous inactivity (i.e. AppleScript having not accessed its data in that time).  Between successive runs of a script, they accumulate, which irks me. _Cont'd..._

Comment: _...Con'td_ But more importantly, the data don't seem to get consistently and reliably overwritten with new data on each successive run on the script, possibly because I declared my orphans with a specific `name` (even though _System Events_ assigns each instance its own `id`).  Deleting every property list at the beginning seems to ensure that the data I'm handling is the most up-to-date version of the data. ☐

Comment: So in the context of this question its the two `property ...` lines that follow the `use application "System Events"` that is the target of `delete every property list item`, if I'm understanding this correctly?

Comment: @user3439894 No, on the very first run, there ought to be zero `property list items` in _System Events'_ cache.  Therefore, nothing will be deleted and the command is gracefully ignored.  It's the `property list item` the script creates with the **`make`** command that gets stored and lingers around, either until it expires naturally; or until _Script Editor_ is restarted; or until one executes a `delete every property list item` command. If you run a few `make` commands then run `get every property list item of app "System Events"`, you'll see what currently exists.

Comment: Okay, got it, and that makes perfect sense! :) I have to admit that personally I'd go for the "mess around with `grep`, `awk`, or `sed` to pattern match text from the raw output" doing it totally as a `bash` script; however if the use of AppleScript is a needed/wanted part of what the OP is doing, this is an excellent answer and a solid way to parse the output. +1

Comment: @user3439894 Actually, I am/was half-expecting a pure shell solution from you.  I partly did it this way to leave you the bash scripting task, and partly because I'm pretty crap at `awk`, so I figured I'd let someone who is more skilled than I handle that.  I would probably personally do it as a shell script; maybe use `plutil` to parse the XML/plist data.  I don't like my repeat loop that successively creates a new shell process for each disk. I would prefer to do a compound shell command in a single process but it was a logistical challenge.  Thanks for the +1!

Comment: Spent the last two days fixing a friends motorcycle then a long sunset and full moon rise ride. Too exhausted today to write any code, and now I need to finish cleaning my motorcycle. Bugs, the only part of a night ride that's not fun!

Comment: @CJK thanks for extensive answer, I will try it tonight and mark as answer if it works for me. 
I'm a C# / C++ game programmer so don't even know what the grep, awk, or sed things are :)
just have trouble with my MacBook mounting an external disk almost 80% off the time, if there is a better way to solve this I'm all ears. Doing it with terminal as the reference says helped, so i though why not do a small apple script that does the whole thing, turns out it's a bit bigger than anticipated.